# ansible inventory, obtaining a variable from another host

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to figure out how best to arrange my inventory, group vars and host vars.  The estate in question involves many Cisco routers connected to a handful of Cisco WAN gateways.  I need to work out how best to divide up groupings so that I can refer to specific details when I roll out a change to a customer.  The routers are fairly simple; each router will be in a group of [routers], of [customer name] and of [router model].

Each Cisco router will be connected to one or two of the WAN gateways.  As an example of the sort of thing I'm looking for, I want to specify the primary WAN gateway, and then from there be able to look up that WGW public IP, BGP AS etc.

And aside from "global variables" as above, I will need to access the details specific to that customer on each WAN gateway.  There are variables I can piece together from information on the CPE, but I'm unsure whether I shouldn't also subdivide the hostvar file for each WAN Gateway into groups for each customer.

So to summarise, when I run a playbook for a host, I need it to access variables from another host in host_vars

Comment: `hostvars['other_inventory_host_name`]` contains the vars from the "other" host.

Answer (score 0):

ok, if I reference the hostname of another host in this hosts hostvars file, i.e.:

```
primary_wgw: WGW001
```

Then in the WAN gateways hostvars file I can have:

```
public_ip: x.x.x.x
test_var: test
test_router_01:
  destination_ip: x.x.x.x
  test: x.x.x.x
```

and I can reference variables like this:

```
- name: test variable
  debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars[primary_wgw]['public_ip'] }}"

- name: test variable
  debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars[primary_wgw][inventory_hostname]['test'] }}"
```